# jquery $(this) not working in coffee script / backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I recently started playing with Backbone and CoffeeScript using Brunch and was wondering why something like this...

```
events: {
  "click .button" : "open",
  "hover .info"   : "hover"
},

hover: =>
  $(this).css("background-color", "#333")
```

..does not work.

From my understanding CoffeeScript has its own version of `this` which could conflict with what jQuery uses but in the documentation I thought `=>` binds it to the current object. I have also tried `->` as well to no avail. Any idea on why this doesn't work?

HTML:

```
<div id='outer'> 
   <div class='.info'> <a href='google.com'> google </a> </div> 
   <div class='.info'> <a href='google.com'> google </a> </div> 
   <div class='.info'> <a href='google.com'> google </a> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at what javascript it's generating?

Comment: yes it's returning the standard $(this).css("background-color", "#333") which is just normal jquery

Comment: try alerting `this` in the hover-function and see what you actually get.

Comment: Even though it's returning the valid jQuery-code doesn't mean that the context is valid.

Comment: I meant to look at the code before your statement to see how the hover function was being set up and how the value of `this` was being set.  You may have to step through it in a debugger to see what's really going on.

Comment: `class='.info'` looks like an error to me, don't you mean `class='info'` (without the .)?

Comment: This is always a problem in Javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents):

> All attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, `this` continues to refer to the view object.

And if `this` is the view object (rather than, say, an HTML element), `$(this)` is fairly meaningless. What you want to do, I believe, is pass the *element* to which the view refers to `$`, e.g.:

```
hover: =>
  $(this.el).css("background-color", "#333")
  # -----^
```

Comment: When I do this it changes the background for all the elements with that class. I think by using the el to refer to the view it affects the entire page and not just the current object

Comment: What does `$(this.el)` return?

Comment: same as previous [object Object] which contains the outer div when checking it out in the console

Comment: What outer div? You haven't shown any markup so I have no way of telling what you're referring to.

Comment: sorry it's something like

<div id='outer'>
    <div class='.info'>
        <a href='google.com'> google </a>
    </div>

    <div class='.info'>
        <a href='google.com'> google </a>
    </div>

    <div class='.info'>
        <a href='google.com'> google </a>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 5):

Jordan's answer is correct with respect to this - if you want the view's element use this.el.

In your case you want the element that triggered the event i.e. the .info element.  This can be retrieved through event.currentTarget[1](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)

```
hover: (e) =>
  $(e.currentTarget).css("background-color", "#333")
```

Answer (score 3):

Jordan and gingerhendrix are both correct, but let me step back a moment to consider the more general question of `=>` vs. `->`.

You've no doubt seen/used code like

```
$('#foo').hover ->
  $(this).css('background-color', '#333')
```

Why does this work? Well, internally, jQuery's hover function looks something like this [heavily stylized, obviously]:

```
hover: (callback) ->
  for el in @
    el.onmouseenter = el.onmouseleave = (e) -> callback.call el, e
```

`callback.call el, e` is just like calling `callback(e)`, except that it makes `this` point to `el` inside of that function call. So that's why `$(this)` gives you a jQuery object wrapped around the element that the hover event is on.

But this wouldn't work if you wrote

```
$('#foo').hover => ...
```

because `=>` *overrides* `call` and `apply`; it forces `this` to always mean the same thing, no matter how the function is called.

Here's the thing: Backbone's `hover` wraps around jQuery's `hover` in such a way that `this` points to the View instance anyway... so it actually doesn't matter in your case whether you use `->` or `=>`. That's why they use `$(this.el)` in [the docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-delegateEvents). And that's great, because you'll almost certainly want to have access to the view's properties when handling events. As gingerhendrix pointed out, `this.el` is going to give you the overall View element, not the specific element receiving the `hover` event; but the event object `e` has what you need (and so much more).

For more on the bound function operator, [check out my book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript).

Answer (score 1):

Well $(this) is not working me to so I did $(event.target). This will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I write my jQuery calls like this when using Coffee Script:

```
$ -> $('#entryBox').val "Placeholder text"
```

I haven't even bothered figuring out why it works yet, but it does work.